# Lightbox script (view.js) doesn't work with tumblr infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I've been hacking up a theme for a tumblr portfolio (http://hirebeamish.tumblr.com/) which includes adding lightbox support using view.js (http://finegoodsmarket.com/view/).

I managed to get everything working so far, but when I have more than 15 items, infinite scroll kicks in, and the whole lightbox thing falls apart. I guess because the new items on the page weren't there when the page was created, the lightbox script doesn't detect them.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get this working somehow? Do I need another lightbox script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so basically your problem is that view.js doesn't auto-update after AJAX calls, which kind of sucks.

You can force the update of view.js like this:

```
new View( $('.view') );
```

You can test this by pasting it into the console after you scrolled all the way down, and now the images will work fine.

However, you have to find the way to run it every time the DOM updates after the infinite scroll kicks in.

So let's do this in another way.
Add this line of code somewhere in your theme:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.imageView', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.viewer').remove(); //This is to remove any previous viewers
    var s = $(this).attr('href');
    var v = new View ($('.imageView')); 
    v.open(); 
    v.show(s);
});
```

What this code does is creates a listener on the whole document, and every time there's a click it runs the function if a clicked element is anchor with a 'view' class.
Then it manually creates a new view with the the array filled with all the images. It's not the best solution as it builds the array every time but should solve your problem.

Hope this helped.

UPDATE: OK so now we'll take the href attribute of the anchor so that we get the real image and not the thumbnail.
It also seems that view.js is setup so that it automatically grabs 'view' class, so change the anchor classes from 'view' to 'imageView' for example. That way we won't open up two lightboxes.
As well, since we are creating a new object every time when we click on an image, we need to remove all previous viewers with remove().

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've implemented your solution and it works (sorta), however I think it has the side effect of opening up the thumbnail size version of the image you click in a new viewer ON TOP of the initial lightbox below.

It's live, if you want to see what I mean.

Comment: OK, that was my fault. I targeted the thumb image instead of the real one. Also you should change the anchor classes so that you dont get two lightboxes. I updated my answer above with the updated code and explanation.

Comment: Almost perfect. So, now I guess we're not calling view.js exactly, because you can no longer page through images with the lightbox up. In the example on the view.js website, you can see that you can click left and right to scroll through the images. This WAS working initially, before we added the custom listener. I think it checks the rel parameter to see which items belong in the same group. Any way to get that working again?

Comment: We are calling view.js but the difference is that the old way it took all the photos at the start and put them into an array, now we're just taking one photo at a time. However, I'll try to play around with it a little bit now and see if I can make it push the new photos to the array so that you have all the functionality.

Comment: Also, the listener now is calling the lightbox script on the permalink page. I can probably fix this myself by adding some conditionals in the theme file... but maybe there's a more elegant way to handle it?

Comment: I updated the answer so that it stores the whole array. Left and right should work now. As for permalink page, is it possible to change it in the template so that anchors don't have imageView class on the permalink pages?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working at all now. I copied in the most recent bit of code, and the screen still darkens, but no image shows up. I've left it live in case you want to diagnose.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. I edited the answer, the brackets in new View ([$('.imageView')]) were extra...so the correct line is: new View ($('.imageView'));

Comment: Works perfectly the first time. However, the second time you bring u the lightbox, I'm seeing the double lightbox problem again. `Repro steps: 1. Load the page. 2. Click on any image. Notice everything is working normally. 3. Click on the background to remove the lightbox. 4. Click on any image AGAIN. 5. Notice that the background is twice as dark, and that when paging through photos, you will see the image you originally clicked open in a second lightbox in the background.` Thanks a million, by the way. I really appreciate all your help.